# Excel Query editor (references other queries or steps)

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery

I am building a tool for our business users. The user will enter a part number and other information into a table, in power query we load this table into a single delimited string that we can then use when creating a new connection to a stored procedure on our database.

The idea is that the stored procedure returns a bill of materials including a few calculated columns based on the other inputs.

I can easily build this solution on my PC and it refreshes the data fine, but whenever I try to refresh data from another computer I get the following error

[image]

Strange thing is that there is no Step named AutoremovedColumns1, but if I look at the error from within Query Editor I get the following error

[image]

My query against the stored procedure looks like this

```
let
    SQL = 
        "EXEC GSCM_Tools.dbo.top_N_BOM_Rev_Lys_V2 " &
        "@Top_Parts = " & PB_List & "," & 
        "@Pct_Threshold = " & Threshold ,

    Source = Sql.Database("sqlserver05.terma.com\gscm", "GSCM_Tools", [Query=SQL])
in
    Source
```

Where PB_List and Threshold derives from two separate tables within the same spreadsheet. Threshold takes a specific row in one table and returns a string ('0.8')

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="OtherSettings"]}[Content],
    Value = Text.Replace(Text.From(Source{0}[Value]), ",", ".")
in
    Value
```

And PB_List combines all data in one table to a single string that I then split within the stored procedure ('259470-022;H;2;5;45;100;1000|GL158K380G03;AN;2;5;45;100;1000'), rows being |-delimited and columns ;-delimited.

```
let
    pbList = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="PB_List"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
        pbList, 
        "Part_Revision", 
        each 
            [TOP_PART] &";"& 
            [Eng Revision] &";"& 
            Text.From([PB 1]) &";"& 
            Text.From([PB 2]) &";"& 
            Text.From([PB 3]) &";"& 
            Text.From([PB 4]) &";"& 
            Text.From([PB 5])),
    ListOfParts = #"Added Custom"[Part_Revision],
    JoinedText = Text.Combine(ListOfParts, "|"),
    PartsFilter = "'" & JoinedText & "'"
in
    PartsFilter
```

I'm wondering why this error does not occur on my PC, but assume it has to do with some sort of caching taking place on my machine, it does make it hard to fix bugs that I cannot recreate though :(

Can you give me a few pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm I think I figured it out, it seems that I might have some ambiguity on my naming of tables/variables etc., seems to work now that I have fixed this (More specifically I call both my table and variable the same name PB_List)

Comment: Did you check "Privacy Level" option? PowerQuery refuses to send data which contains data from a data source to another data source. You are trying to send query which contains information from `Excel.CurrentWorkbook()` data source to `Sql.Database()` data source so PowerQuery refues it, unless Privacy Level option is set to "Always ignore Privacy Level settings".

Comment: I did go through privacy settings, and found that this was not the issue, though it could have been the cause for the firewall error.